# Rectangle unbounded ripple effect

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I know that we can simply by setting `?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` for background property get unbounded ripple effect for a view.

We can also simply have our own ripple drawable to have customized color:

```
<!-- An unbounded blue ripple. --/>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/blue" />
```

The result is an unbounded circle with ripple effect starts from center ripples to corners.

I try to build the same effect with Rectangle and not circle, but I never could find the same effect. for instance I tried following using mask view :

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

More samples : http://blog.stylingandroid.com/ripples-part-3/

The result is a rectangle but not `unbounded`. It will be bounded to the view bounds (as explained for mask in documentation)
As well as ripple effect is different (for me in Android-M Preview version)

I wonder if there is any solution to simply build rectangle unbounded with same ripple effect as default unbounded ripple (as I explained above)?

Or to solve the problem I should go for a custom view?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be unattainable with xml. However, it's doable from code:

1. Make the ripple unbounded by providing `null` for its additional layers (content and mask)
2. Increase hotspot area so the circle ripple goes beyond view's larger dimension (width or height)
3. Clip the canvas with rectangle before drawing

```
fun View.setSelectableItemBackgroundBorderlessRectangle(
    @Px left: Int = 0,
    @Px top: Int = 0,
    @Px right: Int = 0,
    @Px bottom: Int = 0,
) {
    doOnLayout { view ->
        val bounds = Rect(-left, -top, view.width + right, view.height + bottom)

        background = object : RippleDrawable(
            ColorStateList.valueOf(getColorFromAttr(android.R.attr.colorControlHighlight)),
            null,
            null
        ) {
            override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
                canvas.clipRect(bounds)
                super.draw(canvas)
            }
        }.apply {
            setHotspotBounds(bounds.left, bounds.top, bounds.right, bounds.bottom)
        }
    }
}
```